# Simplification mysql query by subquery for finding pair in one table

Tags: mysql, simplify

I have following table in mysql:

```
id | pairType
1  | 2
2  | 2
3  | 1
4  | 1
```

I need get second value to pair by id. I`am able doing this by 2 separated mysql queries, but it would be more comfortable to have it in one.

For example:
first query:

```
SELECT `pairType`
        FROM `tmp`
        WHERE `id` = 1
```

//return 2

second query:

```
SELECT `id`
        FROM `tmp`
        WHERE `id` != 1 AND `pairType` = 2
```

Thank's a lot

Comment: 'second value to pair by id' ?

Comment: looking at your second (resulting) query I can't get why do you need to execute the 1st one? what data from 1st query used in 2nd?

Comment: This is unintelligible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT id
FROM tmp
WHERE pairtype = (SELECT pairtype FROM tmp WHERE id = 1)
    AND id <> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

That is absolutely unclear what are you asking for.

But here are some random guesses:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ee0096/4

```
SELECT t.id
FROM tmp t
INNER JOIN tmp t_
ON t_.pairtype = t.id
   t_.id = 1 ;


SELECT t.id
FROM tmp t
INNER JOIN tmp t_
ON t_.pairtype = t.pairtype
  AND  t_.id = 1 
WHERE t.id != 1
```